# Missing Index Patterns

Tags: logstash, kibana, filebeat, logstash-configuration, elk

I'm missing some index patterns in Kibana and I've been trying to figure out why this is the case. I have installed logstash, elasticsearch and kibana and started the services. How do I get logstash, apache-access etc to show in this section? Only filebeat shows.

[image: Kibana Index Patterns]

I've used the CURL command for the localhost and port to see the indices and only kibana and filebeat are shown there are and apache-access and logstash are no where to be seen.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction to resolving this and being able to see 'logstash' and 'apache-access' under the patterns section.

Answer (score 0):

Data is being saved inside indices in Elasticsearch cluster, in Kibana you can define index-patterns to show multiple indices at the same time.

When you look in the left menu of your screenshot you'll find a menu item called "Index Management", all indices will be shown there, here you'll find the name of the indices that exist in your Elasticsearch cluster.

An index pattern in Kibana is just a (wildcarded) pattern to allow you to see the data.

On the top right of your screenshot you see the button "+ Create Index Pattern", by clicking there you can define a new pattern which will live next to the existing one (filebeat-*).

Once you defined a second one, you'll be able to define which one is the default one chosen when you open Kibana and a dropdown will be available on your discover page in Kibana with the active index-pattern for your discovery at that time.
tash
So in short, press the "create index pattern" button twice entering once logstash* as the pattern and once apache-access* as pattern.